# Shadow in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, shadow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ5il.png)

As you can see there is a shadow around the ticket. I cannot make this because I am using the library (TicketView) and there is a problem with Scallops

HERE IS MY CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#f3f6f9">



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="52.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:elevation="14dp">


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="37.5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/gradient_tickets">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                android:elevation="2dp"
                                android:text="Bus 79"
                                android:textColor="#fefefe"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="37dp"
                                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="69dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/img1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                android:scaleX="0.6"
                                android:scaleY="0.6"
                                android:src="@drawable/arrow_list" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@id/text2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
                                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:text="11/03/2017"
                                android:textColor="#a4158a"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img1"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                android:text="$0.30"
                                android:textColor="#a4158a"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <com.vipulasri.ticketview.TicketView
                                    android:id="@+id/ticketView"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="142dp"
                                    app:ticketBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                                    app:ticketDividerColor="#16191c"
                                    app:ticketDividerDashGap="4dp"
                                    app:ticketDividerDashLength="3dp"
                                    app:ticketDividerPadding="1.5dp"
                                    app:ticketDividerType="dash"
                                    app:ticketDividerWidth="0.5dp"
                                    app:ticketOrientation="horizontal"
                                    app:ticketScallopPositionPercent="25.7"
                                    app:ticketScallopRadius="7dp"
                                    app:ticketShowBorder="false"
                                    app:ticketShowDivider="true"

                                    />



                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="20.5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="16.5dp"
                                    android:elevation="2dp"
                                    android:text="12/03/2017"
                                    android:textColor="#a4158a"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ticketView"
                                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ticketView"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="16.5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                                    android:elevation="2dp"
                                    android:text="$0.30"
                                    android:textColor="#a4158a"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                                    android:elevation="3dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/barcode_img" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>







                    </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
```

I need to have a shadow there but I cannot manage to do it. Also I used the TicketView which is for making the form of the ticket. Could u please say what I need to add there in order to have such a shadow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CardView. There is a parameter which app:cardElevation.

But if it's not possible, You can create a drawable and you can create shadow with using gradient.

Comment: How can I create a gradient for 3 sides only? How can I divide the shape of the drawable into 3 parts?